# Xamarins sharpie pod stops at searching for requested cocoapods

Tags: ios, xamarin, cocoapods, objective-sharpie

I am trying to make an IOS Xamarin binding for the Braintree payment gateway by following these instructions:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/cocoapod
But when i run
sharpie pod init ios BraintreeDropIn
I reaches the line "**Searching for requested CocoaPods**" and then seems to stay there indefinitely
I have tried downgrading Pod to 1.7.5  as some others recommended but that made no difference. Anyone know what could be going wrong?
Sharpie version = 3.4.0-c0f0e73
pod version = 1.7.5
After hanging for a long time it eventually output the message:
error: Failed to run pod list

Answer (score 1):

It was this post from which i originally tried downgrading cocoapods to 1.7.5, having not realised that the first commentor had it workign with cocoapods 1.5.0:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/issues/173
Moving to 1.5.0 solved it for me.

Comment: Will do, wont let me accept it till tomorrow though, any idea why i have to wait two days to accept my own answer?